# Retrieving Retrofit Object in PHP

Tags: php, android, retrofit2

I was sending a `String` using `GET` in Retrofit and it worked well in my PHP server file.

e.g.

```
@GET("add.php")
Call<Void> getData(@Query("value") String value);
```

and this could be retrieved using `$_GET['value']`. This string was a JSON string converted from an object, say of class `Survey`.

Now that this string has become very long, I decided to use `POST` instead of `GET` otherwise I get a `URI too long` error.

My new code is this:

```
@POST("add.php")
Call<Void> getData(@Body Survey survey);
```

My query is, how can I retrieve this data in my PHP file now (since I am not mentioning the `value` parameter anymore).

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34371656/php-get-post-request-content

Answer (score 0):

You could add a header to the call like so

```
@POST("add.php")
Call<Void> getData(@Body Survey survey,
                   @Header("value") String value);
```

And account for the header in the PHP code